# handling of numbers in ORDER BY with the CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Numbers in ORDER BY refer to column ordinal position in the SELECT list.
So the following query is equivalent to ordering by 'C.custid, C.region':

```
SELECT
C.custid, C.region
FROM SALES.Customers AS C
ORDER BY  1, c.region
```

Now if I make use of a CASE statement such that I want the NULL value in region column to be sorted last, then I would do something like:

```
SELECT
C.custid, C.region
FROM SALES.Customers AS C
ORDER BY  CASE WHEN C.region IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, C.region
```

In this case the numbers are treated not as ordinal position of columns but as hard coded values helping to change the sort order.

If my understanding is correct, why this discrepancy? Reason behind it?

Thanks

Comment: In the first case treating `1` as a value doesn't make sense because it will always be the same whereas the case statement could return different values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the documentation for [`order by`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql):

> order_by_expression
>
> Specifies a column or expression on which to sort the query result set. A sort column can be specified as a name or
>   column alias, or a nonnegative integer representing the position of
>   the column in the select list.

The key here is *nonnegative integer* representing the position of
 the column, not *expression*.

An expression can be used for ordering, but wouldn't you be surprised if it happened to pick a column now and then if the expression value was within the number of columns in the select list?

When parsing a statement the database needs to distinguish unambiguously between a positional column or an expression to be sorted, e.g. `Checksum( HatSize )`. The rule in this case is that a integer constant specifies a column by position, any other expression regardless of data type, e.g. a column name or `Len( Name )`, specifies a value to be sorted.

Also note:

> Best Practices
>
> Avoid specifying integers in the ORDER BY clause as positional
>   representations of the columns in the select list.

Comment: 1) Thanks for bringing it up but I do know the best practice around this. 2) The case statement returns expressions and in this case the type of the expression is resolved to be a integer constant(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/expressions-transact-sql and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql). So the difference is very subtle in this case but can be used to explain this behavior. Thanks

Comment: I've added to the answer re: parsing. When the documentation says "integer" it means an [integer constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql), not an expression that evaluates to an integer type. In [`CREATE [ OR ALTER ] { PROC | PROCEDURE } [schema_name.] procedure_name [ ; number ]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql) the rarely used _number_ is an "optional integer". That's another place that an expression wouldn't make sense, but an integer has a purpose.